# Oracle update 2 tables in one query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have 2 tables with same column name
and same condition for update

does I can run it with single query (without create view or something like this)

this is the 2 query that I want to combine to single query

```
update client set  cityid =76  where cityid =2 
update agent_ set  cityid =76  where cityid =2
```

Thanks

Comment: `update` only updates one table at a time.

Comment: No, you can't combine two updates in a single query. The options I see are: 1) Creating a stored procedure to execute both updates, or 2) Add a trigger on one of the table that updates the other automatically. None of these is difficult but they are not trivial either. Better to run both statements.

Comment: You can create a PROCEDURE to update the tables with parameters, if the value must be the same, you can do yout approach.